# How to draw graphs in classic ASP?

Tags: graph, asp-classic

Suppose I have the the following two arrays in a classic ASP file:

```
<%

    Dim x(5)
    x(0) = 0
    x(1) = 1
    x(2) = 2
    x(3) = 3
    x(4) = 4

    Dim y(5)
    y(0) = 10
    y(1) = 20
    y(2) = 15
    y(3) = 20
    y(4) = 5


%>
```

Will i be able to draw a simple line graph with an x an y axis and use the array data above to plot the dots and draw in lines. The graph must then be displayed in the asp file when i load it in the browser. I find it a bit difficult to find good examples on drawing graphs in ASP. Can someone please give me a direction on where to look for good examples and make it easier to understand?

Comment: Since the rendering is done on the client using HTML + CSS the server-side code really has little to do with it, other than populating values. There are plenty of HTML + CSS solutions for graphing. Go do some research.

Comment: If you have access to different server running ASP.NET (or better yet can also write ASP.NET on same server) you can write web service that will get those arrays as input and send back graph image as output then classic ASP will consume it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to draw / render the graph in asp - you're just asking for pain.

There are many great charting libraries out there that will render data for you, in both vector, svg & whatever else you could possibly want.

Looking at your data; i can see your after a basic example - in that case may i suggest the Google Chart API?

Here is an example using your data:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'StackOverflow!'],
    ['0',   10],
    ['1',   20],
    ['2',   15],
    ['3',   20],
    ['4',   5]
  ]);

  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 20}}
          );
}
```

Have your classic asp spit out the above javascript to the client and Google Chart API will do the rest:

[image]

You can play with the google charts api using their playground tool:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

To use the above javascript in one of your pages, you'll need to include the relevent api js libs as described here:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs